# For loop to put images side by side

Tags: html, css, for-loop

Okay I been trying to work this out but unable too. I have a for loop which grabs the images but they are vertical. I would like them side by side. I am confused on what to do. I have it listed in a sidebar.

```
<div class="socialGroup">
    <xen:include template="cz_groups_group_title" />
</div>

</xen:foreach>
```

Comment: I am sorry but i would like them side by side in columns of two. So 1 image and then 2nd. Then the third on the next line . etc.

Comment: See my answer with demo of 5 images in 1 row, if any thing i am lagging here then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using css. Add a ul to the social group class then li to the group title and style them using css. You can set the li width and height.

```
<div class="socialGroup">
  <ul>
     <li><xen:include template="cz_groups_group_title" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</xen:foreach>
```

Comment: is there any way i can have maybe 5 on a row ? Or how to adjust for that via css ?

Comment: Yes you can have how many you would like on a row. I have created an example so you can see how to do something like so. You can change the width of the sidebar to add more photos on a line. http://jsfiddle.net/kKuNJ/

Comment: Yeah after i typed it i thought about just the width of sidebar to accommodate the images. Thank you works great.

Answer (score 1):

See the below fiddle for HTML Structure and Css rules for 5 images in 1 row.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fcfj/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2fcfj/embedded/result/